# Permissions - Files unzipped using unzip command do not contain any permission settings

Tags: c#, shell, permissions, unzip, c#-ziparchive

I extract a file in the macos terminal using the unzip command. But I found that the unzipped file did not give any permission:

```sh
$ unzip '/Users/menghanyu/foo.zip' -d '/Users/menghanyu/foo-unzip'
```

```sh
cd /Users/menghanyu/foo-unzip
ls -la
```

```sh
----------    1 menghanyu  staff  28998 11 20 14:30 Foo.json
----------    1 menghanyu  staff  28998 11 20 14:30 Bar.json
```

I tried to use `-K` and it didn't work. (because i can't ensure that the zip file will have a permission flag.)

```sh
$ unzip -K '/Users/menghanyu/foo.zip' -d '/Users/menghanyu/foo-unzip'
```

How can I make the extracted files consistent with the permissions of the parent folder?

**zipinfo**

```sh
Archive:  foo.zip
Zip file size: 57996 bytes, number of entries: 2
?---------  2.0 unx   28998 b- defN 19-Nov-20 14:30 Foo.json
?---------  2.0 unx   28998 b- defN 19-Nov-20 14:30 Bar.json
```

zipinfo command tells us that the umask is not set, but the c# `ZipArchive` does not provide the corresponding api, what should I do?

```cs
public class ZipArchiveEntry
{
    public ZipArchive Archive { get; }
    public long CompressedLength { get; }
    public string FullName { get; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastWriteTime { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public void Delete();
    public Stream Open();
    public override string ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you try sth like `chmod -R u=rw foo/unzip`? `unzip` doesn't have an option for changing permissions afaik

Comment: @oguz ismail The unzip command is executed by the program. I can't ensure that the program has the permission to execute chmod. (And my program is designed to not suggest use sudo to run)

Comment: What's your umask?

Comment: Please provide `zipinfo /Users/menghanyu/foo.zip`. May be permissions are lost between umask and permissions stored inside ZIP

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17342 This is the problem caused by dotnet itself.

Comment: @MengHanYu Looks like the problem is in the ZIP. Can you share the code/command that creates the zip file ?

Comment: @dash-o Already know the answer, This is due to the defect of dotnet itself. See my last comment.